# How could I know an Uncertain type parameters' size

Tags: c

```
const static int VECTOR_BASIC_LENGTH = 20;
struct m_vector
{
    void*               my_vector;
    size_t              my_capacity;
    size_t              my_head;
};

typedef struct m_vector Vector;

Vector creat_Vector(size_t size,void *judge)
{
    Vector _vector;     
    size = size?size:VECTOR_BASIC_LENGTH;
    _vector.my_capacity = size;
    _vector.my_head     = 0;
    //How I write the following two lines
    _vector.my_vector = malloc(sizeof(*judge) * size);
    return _vector;
}
```

The type of judge is uncertain,so I pass a void pointer as a parameters.I need the size of `*judge` to allocate memory to `_vector.my_vector`,for example if I use:

```
int *a;
creat_Vector(5,a);
```

I want the following line:

```
_vector.my_vector = malloc(sizeof(*judge)*size);
```

is equal to:

```
_vector.my_vector = malloc(sizeof(*a)*5);
```

How could I achieve this function.Using pure C

Comment: You can't. You need to carry around some type informations.

Comment: Does that mean I have to write some function which only difference in parameters？

Comment: Thats what you are going to do RIGHT NOW!! :D

Comment: Be aware that you return local function data from `creat_Vector`. Rethink this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a forbidden thing done in your code.
You statically (at compile time) allocate/declare a local `_vector` of type `Vector` in your function `creat_Vector`. Then you return this object to the outside world. However, when you are exiting your function, all local data is dead. So, you should absolutely rethink this.

One suggestion would be:

```
int init_Vector(Vector* _vect, size_t size, unsigned int ptr_size)
{
    size = size?size:VECTOR_BASIC_LENGTH;
    _vect->my_capacity = size;
    _vect->my_head     = 0;
    _vect->my_vector   = malloc(size*ptr_size);
    if (_vect->my_vector) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Then:

```
Vector _vector;
char *a;

if (init_Vector(&_vector, 5, sizeof(char)) == 0) {
    printf("Success!\n");
}
else {
    printf("Failure!\n");
    /* treat appropriately (return error code/exit) */
}

/* do whatever with a (if needed) and _vector*/
```

Comment: Oh yes, thats a nice solution, though.

Comment: @ckruczek: I have just noticed that local function data is being returned by `creat_Vector`, which is simply unaccepted. I've proposed a possible solution.

Comment: Yep totally agreed in that.